# How to link webform through vb.net code parsing data.

Tags: vb.net, webforms

net and I am trying to create a project that will handle questions from a text file and save the answers to a new text file. I was searching the internet and I couldn't find an example for linking two webform through vb code so here is my problem:

I want to preprocess a text file that will be uploaded in a specific form through vb.net . That context is parsed in a string table. Now I want that table to pass over to the rest of my forms which they will handle the data in order to modify the below webform. Here is where I want to call the other forms in order.

```
Private Sub BtdContinue_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtdContinue.Click
    If FileUpl.PostedFile IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim finalTextTable(rows.Length, 4) As String
        'Preprocess
        'for i=0 to finalTextTable.Lenght-1
        '   for j=0 to 4
               'Call the other web form from here in a loop if possible
    End if
```

Here is my web form with labels and images that I want every question to change it
[image: Webform that I am trying to dynamically add data]

> I also want to be able to go to the previous webform through a
> previous button.

Comment: Do you want the methods in the other forms to modify the data or to modify the controls?

Comment: I want to modify the controls and to know which check box (answer) was been chosen. Thank you

Comment: What is the connection between the other forms and this one?

Comment: Well i think there is no connection! I don't know how to establish a connection to be honest

Comment: Sorry, I meant logical connection rather than some communication connection. If two (or more) forms have some code that they both use, sometimes it is better to put it into a separate class in its own file and call that from each form. Also, you can store data in session variables to persist it between forms: [ASP.NET Session State Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx).

Comment: Ok so I can I store my data in session. How I can call a new webform that I want to be opened from the current form?

Comment: An ordinary hyperlink `<a href="otherform.aspx">Go to other page</a>` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i did understand your question correctly you are asking to redirect the data from the preprocessed text file to another form. The easiest solution i can think of is by using session variables. After you have preprocessed your text file and stored it into a dataTable you should add the following:

```
'Set the value of DataTable to session
  Session("DataTb") = finalTextTable
'Perform your Redirect
  Response.Redirect("FormB.aspx");
```

The above code should save the table into a session variable accessible by FormB.aspx. You can then handle the table in the second form as you wish.